# Change color of part text css

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the `.io` green, but not sure how to do this via css

```css
#logo {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Expired.io</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put .io in a span element and style that.

```css
#logo {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
}
#logo span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Expired<span>.io</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.span-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Expired<span class="span-green">.io</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this below, it's simple, just add a new html tag.

```css
.someClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Expired<span class="someClass">.io</span></a>
```